# Query to delete all records from table and its relateds on another 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I'm ussing Mysql 10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 and I have a situation.

I have 3 tables:

```
|-Persons-  |
| Id        |
| Name      |
| Email     |
| Date_Last |
------------
| -Routes- |
|Id        |
|Persons_id|
|Date      |
------------
|-Payments-|
|Id        |
|Persons_id|
|Total     |
------------
```

We are cleaning the DB from non-active Persons.
I need to delete all records from Persons where Date_Last > 1 year from now and all records saved on Routes and Paymets from this person.

I.e. A person had about 10 Routes and more than 8,000 Payments.

I can't figure out how to do it in a Query.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create correct FOREIGN key with correct ON DELETE CASCADE action option. Then simply delete rows from main table - all related rows from slave tables will be deleted automatically.

Comment: I can't, because sometimes Persons are deleted manually on Front End and we need to keep their Routes and Payments on our records.

Comment: From the other side I doubt that delete data about payments is good practice. Think about soft deletion.

Comment: still need the query, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is first find out what users have been inactive for one 1year or more.
something like

```
select * from Persons where Date_last > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())
```

or find another way to load up all users

After that you can go a step further

```
Delete from routes where person_ID in (select ID from Persons where Date_last > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) )
```

and the same for payments

```
Delete from Payments where person_ID in (select ID from Persons where Date_last  DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) )
```

be careful when you handle commands like this small mistakes can cause you a lot of data.

try those commands if you want but I first suggest changing all Delete to select *
So you can know the data that you are going to delete is correct.
Hope this can guide you to what you need to do

NOTE: Please dont run the above sql if you dont test it 1st. if it works it might delete data you want

Comment: Test with "Select *" instead of "Delete" and it only returns one record. With "Delete" will loop all the table?

Comment: no it will delete only that one user .  maybe the way I am picking the date is not working .
What do you get if you select * from Persons where Date_last > DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate())

Comment: get all records (102,262)

Comment: I am sorry your answer confuses me,  get all records of the database?  or all the users who are inactive for over one year ? 
if you do a select  DATEADD(year, -1, GetDate()) you will get this exact data + time 
so the select that brings 195k results . 
should bring the same. or a similar number to the above. unless if none of the inactive users made any actions that affected that 2 tables. 

Try modifying that query above and you will find the solution. its how you can do it.  
you will need to edit the nested query to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

> We are cleaning the DB from non-active Persons. I need to delete all records from Persons where Date_Last > 1 year from now and all records saved on Routes and Paymets from this person.

```sql
DELETE Persons, Routes, Payments
FROM Persons
JOIN Routes ON Persons.Id = Routes.Persons_Id
JOIN Payments ON Persons.Id = Payments.Persons_Id
WHERE Persons.Date_Last < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

If it is possible that there exists a row in `Persons` which have no related row in `Routes` and/or `Payments` then use LEFT JOIN for according slave table.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a791fa27888b3d37ce8c320d4cf9c492
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eea61c4684cc4cbc9cb6f1fe80ce1b6a
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8539eb719c85d314cba2a3880b8d6b5b
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63c7befdb951b537c9e63199367076b8